# Do craft numbers and hat levels affect the cost of the item?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Every time I see people trading, some of them seem to highlight the fact that their hats are of 'collector's level'. Either that, or they are selling crafted hats with special craft numbers on them. One person even commented on my trade that my hat is of level 42 and that I should up my price. I have no idea whether he is lying to me or not.

[image]

As for craft numbers, is a misc with this craft number worth more than usual?

**Do these small factors really affect the value of an item? If it does, could someone provide a list of Hat levels and craft numbers that are worth significantly more?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hats are very <strike>useless</strike>  sentimental items. Because of that, the pricing of a hat is dependent on what someone will pay for it. As "42" is a special number, it is true that it may be cooler than a hat that's not level 42. The same thing can go for Craft #'s. Hats with craft numbers below 100 are the first 100 hats to be made. This can also be special because people like having "antique" items.

There isn't really a list of levels and numbers that are worth more. Any sequence you think is cool can make a hat be worth more, such as 42, 1234, or 9001. It's all really opinion based

Comment: how about for my specific craft hat? the Wilson weave? is it worth more? if so, how much more?

Comment: I would say it is worth maybe 2.66ref for that specific case going by trade.tf/spreadsheet

Comment: @DavidToh It is only worth more if you can find someone interested in the craft number 1111. Normal people would be un-interested in it outside of being a normal hat. But, the "below 100" ones do go for more, and are easy to find buyers.